# best way to increase upload speed in aws and laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I am running an application which requires the user to upload large files.

My server is deployed in `AWS singpore` region. When someone upload the files from Singapore or nearest location upload is faster. But same uploading from USA or australia which are far from my server location taking long time for upload the same file.

Is there a way I can increase the upload speed regardless of the location?

Is there any AWS service that will help me resolve this issue?

I am using laravel 7 as my backend application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are uploading to an EC2 instance, and not S3.

I would start by modifying the code to upload the large files to S3.  Then, you have a few options.  AWS has a service called Transfer Acceleration which may help speed up the transfers.

If you have a global audience, you could also consider deploying your application across multiple regions, and using Route53 latency-based routing to ensure your end users are connected to the closest region.

Comment: Application cross multiple zones is best suites for me.